# Microprocessor and Microcontroller Compilation Differences

Tags: c, compilation, linker, microcontroller, microprocessors

I am trying to understand the differences in the C/C++ compilation process (Compiler/linker/locator etc..) between a microcontroller and a microprocessor.

For example, for a microcontroller, we can provide the linker script to specify the actual physical memory location the program should be executed. However, in a microprocessor where there are multiple programs running, we are unable to provide the actual addresses to load the program.

I would like to know how this compilation handles in a microprocessor and a microcontroller.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I deleted my comment, your answer below covers this very well. You can delete your comment too, I'll delete this comment as well in a while.

Comment: You provide the addresses for both, there is really no difference.  For the mcu, assuming the bare-metal application, you specify physical addresses.  for applications on an operating system (some mcu, or full sized processors) you specify the virtual address in linking (usually the toolchain default is prepared for you with the operating specific address space).

Comment: So no difference at all as far as how things are compiled and linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to understand the differences in the C/C++ compilation process (Compiler/linker/locator etc..) between a microcontroller and a microprocessor.

None by itself.

The difference might be that on a microcontroller you *typically* don't have an operating system that supports any run-time loading of shared libraries, but that's not necessarily the case (NuttX and others).

> For example, for a microcontroller, we can provide the linker script to specify the actual physical memory location the program should be executed.

You can do the same with a microprocessor.

You're trying to make a distinction where there is none: a microcontroller is just a microprocessor with an embedded target market and typically, integrated memory in-package. That's it.

> However, in a microprocessor where there are multiple programs running,

this can (and doesn't have to) be the case on both microcontrollers and microprocessors.

You mean "on microprocessors, we typically use a multitasking operating system. Can we, on such an operating system..."

> we are unable to provide the actual addresses to load the program.

That's not true. Often, such operating systems offer address space randomization and you can compile relocateable code – but the same can (and is!) done for microcontrollers.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Many thanks for the reply. I have one question regarding the linker/locator. In a linker file, we can specify the data/code address locations. I can understand this for a microcontroller running a single application. But in a microprocessor with an OS, there can be multiple applications running on memory. In this case, how do we know that the linker script allocates the actual address space?

Comment: again, this has **nothing** to do with microprocessor vs microcontroller, but with your system offering each task a memory space of its own. so, yes, you can do *exactly* the same on any microprocessor: that's what memory mapping allows you to do. The memory addresses your program see have very little to do with the physical memory addresses used by the hardware when your microcontroller or microprocessor has a MMU and your OS on the microcontroller or microprocessor uses that to offer per-process address spaces, and then each program can use whatever address it likes.

Comment: Hi Marcus, so is it correct to say that for both Micrcontrollers and Microprocessors the physical memory address of the code is decided by the MMU?

Comment: @radar101 Many microcontroller parts do not have an MMU.  Many popular ones have two buses, one for program and one for RAM, with the only "encoding" being one is addressed by the program counter and one is address by the *program.*

Comment: @radar101 no, that is not right! as Tom correctly says, some microcontrollers don't have an MMU, some do, but whether or not you're using the MMU on your micrococontroller or your microprocessor (and how) is a different question!

Answer (score 2):

The terms *microcontroller* and *microprocessor* have no reliable definition, they are used rather randomly and intermixed by different engineers and manufacturers. The consensus is that microcontrollers are simpler, have less resources and are meant more for "real-time-y" embedded tasks. Microprocessor are slightly more complex, have more resources and are meant more for "general" tasks. Various terms like MMU, embedded Flash/RAM, external Flash/RAM are thrown around. If this sounds vague - it is. Don't rely on those terms.

You need to look at specific features on a micro which enable your abilities as a software engineer. The most basic one is MMU - this defines if you can have virtual memory or not. This in turn defines whether it supports an OS which runs processes in separate memory regions or it's all one big continuous pile of memory with addressing hardwired (in which case you still get an OS but it has much less to do). Linking depends a lot on that distinction.

Then a system which runs processes in isolated memory regions typically needs to load the process code into RAM before executing it, which requires (much) more RAM, which is typically solved by an external RAM chip, which requires an MMU.

But the classic definition of a microcontroller is: no MMU, embedded Flash and/or RAM. Classic microprocessor is: MMU, external storage and RAM. There are more exceptions than rules.

Comment: *There are more exceptions than rules.* exactly! And the thing not to forget here is that OP asked about "in practice, what's the difference in compiling" and the truth there is: well, it depends, and the line really isn't drawn at what some textbook calls a microcontroller or a microprocessor. This is a very nice answer, and I'm thankful for its existence, +1.